# Como listar usuário e criar novos dentro do Modal C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modal, model

estou tendo um problema em um projeto e gostaria da ajuda de vocês. Na pagina Index onde estou listando os contatos tem um botão que abri um modal para poder criar um novo contato. O problema é que como posso usar somente um model, estou tendo dificuldades para fazer isso na mesma página, já que nunca fiz dessa forma. Ainda tenho o item do tipo que precisa listar os tipos cadastrados. Segue os códigos abaixo:

```
Index:

@model ContactModel;
@*model List<ContactModel>;*@
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contacts";
}
<div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add">Adicionar</button>
</div>

<br />

<div class="text-center">
    <h3>Contacts List</h3>
</div>

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                <th scope="col">Data de nascimento</th>
                <th scope="col">CPF</th>
                <th scope="col">Sexo</th>
                <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                <th scope="col">Ativo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableContact">
            @*@if (Model != null && Model.Any())
            {
                foreach (ContactModel contato in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">@contato.Id</th>
                        <td>@contato.Nome</td>
                        <td>@contato.DataNascimento</td>
                        <td>@contato.Cpf</td>
                        <td>@contato.Sexo</td>
                        <td>@contato.Tipo</td>
                        <td>@contato.Ativo</td>
                        @*<td>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <a role="button" asp-router-id="@contato.Id" asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">Editar</a>
                <a role="button" asp-router-id="@contato.Id" asp-controller="" asp-action="" class="">Apagar</a>
                </div>
                </td>*@
                    @*</tr>
                }
            }*@
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="modal" id="Add" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Novo Contato</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Nome</label>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Alex da Silva">
                    </div>
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Data de Nascimento</label> <br />
                            <input id="nascimento" asp-for="DataNascimento" type="date" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Sexo</label>
                            <select class="form-control" asp-for="Sexo" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                                <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="Ativo" value="true" />
                            <label>Pessoa Ativa</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">CPF</label>
                            <input type="text" asp-for="Cpf" class="form-control cpf-mask" data-mask="000.000.000-00" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="000.000.000-00">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Tipo</label>
                            <select class="form-control" asp-for="Tipo" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                <option>Programador</option>
                            </select>
                            <br />
                            <a type="button" id="addTipo" class="btn btn-info btn-md" asp-controller="Type" asp-action="Index">Não encontrou o tipo?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Contato Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TesteEngegraph.Models;
using TesteEngegraph.Repositorio;

namespace TesteEngegraph.Controllers
{
    public class Contact : Controller
    {
        private readonly IContatoRepositorio _contatoRepositorio;

        public Contact(IContatoRepositorio contatoRepositorio)
        {
            _contatoRepositorio = contatoRepositorio;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // List<ContactModel> contatos = _contatoRepositorio.All();
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult List()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(ContactModel contato)
        {
            _contatoRepositorio.Adicionar(contato);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TesteEngegraph.Models
{
    public class ContactModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
        public string Cpf { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public TypeModel Tipo { get; set; }
        public Boolean Ativo { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize [Partial Views](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Além de deixar o seu código mais organizado, voce consegue reaproveitar esse código.
Como é um formulario de cadastro, acredito que voce consiga usa-lo para updates.

Crie uma outra `View` com apenas o conteudo do seu Form.

Dai seu modal ficaria mais ou menos assim

```
      <form asp-controller="Contact" asp-action="Create" method="post">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName.cshtml")
      </form>
```

Onde o `_PartialName.cshtml` seria o caminho  da sua `View`

Comment: Obrigado amigo, ajudou muito!